# What does it mean for an object to not be following a definition based on some implication

Tags: logic, markov-chains

I want to get a deeper understanding of what being an object that doesn't follow a  definition means in terms of predicates and logical operators.

Suppose the following definition of the closedness of a subset of states $C$ from a set of states $E$:

$C$ is closed means that(I guess you can think of "means that" as a logical equivalence)

if  "$i \in C \land i,j \in E \land i\to j$" then "$j \in C$",
which can be rewritten as

"$i \in C \land i,j \in E \land i\to j$" $\implies$ "$j \in C$"

Note: $\to$ is meant here as some property between two states

then how could you define the fact that $C$ isn't closed in terms of logical operators: $\in, \land, \lnot, \lor, \implies $...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for, it's really clear with what you wrote, why don't you post that as an answer rather than a comment so that I accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full defintion is :

> "$C$ is *closed* **iff** for all $i,j ∈ E$, if $i∈C$ and $i→j$, then $j∈C$".

The negation of $P ⇒ Q$ is $P ∧ ¬Q$. Thus, we have:

> "$C$ is *not closed* **iff** there are $i,j ∈ E$ such that: $i∈C$ and $i→j$ and $j∉C$".